# react-select - Open Select on selected value click (multiselect)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using `react-select` with multi-selection enabled. How can I force the drop-down menu to open, on a selected value click?

Here is a snippet of the code so far:

```
[...]
valueClick(value) {
    this.DOMNode.focus();
},

<Select
    multi={this.state.multi}
    onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
    options={options}
    ref={(ref)=>{this.DOMNode = ref}}
    autosize={false}
    openOnFocus={true}
    value={value}
    onValueClick={this.valueClick}
/>
[...]
```

As you can see, I am trying to employ the focus functionality to force the menu to open, as [suggested by the creator](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1989) of the component. I have set the `openOnFocus` variable to `true` and manually set a `ref` to the component itself. You can also see the function that calls the `focus()` method above.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

There is a new prop, `menuIsOpen`. All you need to add is `menuIsOpen={true}` and it will stay open.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a property `menuIsOpen` to control that in the new version.